# How to apply a patch to a package without upgrading?

Tags: osx, upgrade

When I tried to use `google-translate.el`, I got a `Failed to search TKK` error.

And according to [this page](https://github.com/atykhonov/google-translate/issues/52) the error caused by [bug#11788](http://emacs.1067599.n8.nabble.com/bug-11788-url-http-does-not-properly-handle-https-over-proxy-td46070.html).

So I have to upgrade `Emacs 26` or apply the patch. But latest emacs in MacOS is `25.2`. And I cound't find where is the `*.el` files for the patch.

How can I avoid this issue? I just want to use `google-translate.el`.

I'm using `Emacs 25.2 (9.0)`.

Comment: You can use `C-h l google-translate` (where `C-h l` calls `find-library`) to locate the code.  One simple option is to `require` the package, and then apply the patch by putting it *after* the `require` statement in your `init` file.  Emacs will just reevaluate the relevant code.

Comment: (following up on @Dan's comment) `C-h l` is `view-lossage` by default, and the patch is against `url-http.el` (comes with emacs) so the command you should use is `M-x find-library RET url-http RET` to find the file to patch.

Comment: Btw this questions looks more like a generic question on how to patch a file, than a specific question "I can't find this file, where is it?"

Comment: Oops!  I must have rebound that key sequence a long time ago and forgot that it wasn't standard.

Comment: Thanks, I found the file. The file was in `/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/Resources/lisp/url/`.